# Writing templates for rsyslog

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

When I'm trying to send log from rsyslog to syslog-ng, the hostnames are getting shortened. Instead of inbound.server.com, I only recieve inbound at the syslog-ng side even though I have FQDN option enabled at receiving side.

THe syslog-ng servers works perfectly when I use syslog to send the logs so there is some problem at the sending side.

How can I specifically specify in the template of rsyslog to write full hostnames?

I also did a [post on ML](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/rsyslog/users/8473#8473) and they said to add a custom template. I'm completely new to rsyslog and just started reading the doc so have no idea how to do so.